# How can I make sure all music in the music app outputs at the same volume?

Tags: macos, mac, audio, music, music.app

My music library has music from a large number of sources, which means that the volume of one song can be very different from that of another, and I'm trying to figure out a good way to make it so that all the songs output at the same volume, since it's very irritating having to constantly adjust the volume every time a song changes.

I've tried doing it by ear with the `volume adjust` option in each song, but this really isn't precise enough. I've also tried using the Sound Check option in Playback settings, but there's a very irritating bug which means that if you pause the music, then play it again, the Sound Check takes a few seconds to adjust the song to the correct volume, so if it's too loud then you get blasted by music for a few seconds before it returns to normal. I have attempted to fix this by making sure my system is up-to-date, and starting Music in Safe Mode (by holding Option-Command when launching), but to no avail.

The only other option I've thought of is using FFmpeg to go through all the songs in my music library and normalise them to a consistent LUFS range. However, I haven't been able to find very clear instructions on the internet about how to do this, and it's also a destructive action, which makes it not ideal. Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple have seemingly fixed the bug with the Sound Check feature in Apple Music, so this is what I will use going forward.

Answer (score 0):

LUFS is really the only way to do it. This has long been a major irritation for me too, as Apple's Sound-Check is purely peak-based & utterly hopeless when it comes to levelling classical or 70s tracks alongside loudness war tracks of the past decade.

That this requires re-compressing is something I decided I would bear, as I mainly use my iTunes library for listening on the go or in the car, where absolute quality is less important to me than acceptable level-matching.

I don't know how you would batch it in ffmpeg, I'm afraid.
I had been trying to find something I could batch this on for quite some time. I eventually discovered [Myriad](https://www.zynaptiq.com/macaudioapps/) which unfortunately isn't available for purchase right now, having recently gone through a change of ownership. I managed to find a friend who let me use his machine for an afternoon to do this. The download does have a trial period, but I haven't checked to see what limitations are imposed - hopefully you could get a complete library conversion from the trial, even if you have to sub-divide your source.
For want of a better set of values, I went with the commonly-accepted -14dBFS & I have to say, I've never been happier.

Myriad can be set to save out in a new folder an exact match of the input hierarchy without touching the originals. One great advantage of Myriad for this is that it keeps each file-type as it re-converts.
Then it was just a case of swapping folders after conversion, leaving iTunes absolutely non the wiser that anything had changed. Then for my iPhone, I did a sync with no tunes, followed by another with the entire library re-added [simply uncheck the sync box, then re-check for the second pass]… et voilà!
Once you do this, remember to switch off Sound Check, or you get playback values that are no longer relevant to the new tracks.